# Number Theory/Quadratic Number Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> Show that if $u,v,x,y$ are positive integers for which
>   $u^2+2v^2=x^2+2y^2=p$ a prime number, then $u=x$ and $v=y$.

I get that if we had $\alpha=u+v\sqrt{-2} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, then the norm is $u^2+2v^2=p$.
I also know that in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, the only invertible elements are $\pm 1$

I'm not sure how to put these facts together to prove the required statement though.

Comment: Hint: Ie if those two elements have the same norm, what happens if you divide one by another?

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a UFD, can you conclude?

Comment: I don't know what would happen if I divide two elements of the same norm by each other. I know it has unique factorisation, but I don't know how to conclude from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $N(u\pm v\sqrt{-2})=p$ prime you get that $u\pm v\sqrt{-2}$ are irreducible. Similarly for $x\pm y\sqrt{-2}$. But, as you were told in the comments by Daniel Fischer, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a UFD, and therefore the irreducible elements are prime. From $(u-v\sqrt{-2})(u+v\sqrt{-2})=(x-y\sqrt{-2})(x+y\sqrt{-2})$ you can conclude.

Comment: Why do you have $\pm v$ but not $\pm u$?

Comment: @Mathsstudent Good question! Because this is a possible (out of few) decomposition of $u^2+2v^2$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$. If you want to use another one, feel free to do it.